# Is it possible to remove selected bookmarks (aka outlines)?

Tags: itext7

Can existing bookmarks be removed from the outline tree of a document using iText 7? The PdfOutline class has methods to add outlines, but there are none to remove one.

I tried selectively copying outlines to a list, removing all the existing outlines with `PdfDocument.getCatalog.remove(PdfName.Outlines)`, and then repopulating the document's outline with the elements of my list. The new outline came out the way I wanted it, but when I clicked on any of the bookmarks, they took me to incorrect locations within the document.

Comment: Hi, right now there is no good option to easily remove a single outline but this is indeed a valid use case that iText should support. You can take a look at `PdfOutline#removeOutline` in the [source code](https://github.com/itext/itext7/blob/d6745af01514a8f36260f737a6d60482e1e950c6/kernel/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/kernel/pdf/PdfOutline.java#L322) and implement something similar yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `7.1.12-SNAPSHOT` version you can already remove an outline (and all its children recursively) with the public API:

```
PdfOutline root = pdfDocument.getOutlines(true);
// Getting third child (as indices are 0-based)
PdfOutline toRemove = root.getAllChildren().get(2);
// Removing outline and all its children recursively (so we are removing a subtree)
toRemove.removeOutline();
```